# why does scanner instance only read 3 lines of code

Tags: java, android

I am trying to save preferences chosen by user to a text file. When I save something then try to add info to it, it is overwritten. I checked the logs and it seems when I read the file to check if there is anything written before and it only reads 3 lines even though I checked the files and it has 6 lines.

I call method called `savefiles` with an instance of class `SoundDetails` which I have written below the `saveFiles` method:

```
   public static void saveFiles(SoundDetails s) {
        try {
        Scanner readDatabasetoSave  = new Scanner(file);
        PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(file);
        String everyThing = "";
        while(readDatabasetoSave.hasNext()){
            everyThing += readDatabasetoSave.nextLine();
            Log.e(everyThing, everyThing);
        }
        int index = everyThing.indexOf('#');

        if(index != -1){
            everyThing = everyThing.substring(0,index); 
        }
        everyThing = everyThing + s.name + "\n" +s.time + "\n" + s.onoff +"\n";
        Log.d("everything final", everyThing);
        //Log.e("everything",everyThing);
        for(boolean b : s.daysofweek){
            if(b == true){
                everyThing += "T";
            }
            else{
                everyThing += "F";
            }
        }
        everyThing += "\n";
        for(boolean b : s.sensors){
            if(b == true){
                everyThing += "T";
            }
            else{
                everyThing += "F";
            }
        }
        everyThing += "\n"+s.profile+"#";
        write.print(everyThing);
        write.close(); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("error occured", e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

Here is `SoundDetails` class:

```
public class SoundDetails {
    public boolean[] sensors ; // wifi gps 3g bluetooth airplane
    public boolean[] daysofweek ;
    public boolean onoff ;
    public String profile;
    public String name;
    public String time;
    public SoundDetails(boolean[] sensors, boolean[] daysofweek,String profile,boolean onoff,String name,String time){
        this.sensors = sensors;
        this.daysofweek = daysofweek;
        this.profile = profile;
        this.onoff = onoff;
        this.name = name;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Comment: btw my txt file looks like this name 
12:30 (thats time but its written as a string)
false (also a string)
TFTFFTF (T and F represent True or false)
FFFFF
0# (hash tag indicates first setting is done and next txt is for the 2nd settings pref)

Comment: What are the results of the Log statements?

Comment: Shouldn't matter but since you use nextLine() you should use hasNextLine()

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, without diving into this too deeply, it seems that the issue may be that you're using indexOf...

```
    int index = everyThing.indexOf('#');

    if(index != -1){
        everyThing = everyThing.substring(0,index); 
    }
```

...when, judging by the rest of your code, I imagine you actually are looking for the last index:

```
    int index = everyThing.lastIndexOf('#');

    if(index != -1){
        everyThing = everyThing.substring(0,index); 
    }
```

Also, it's usually a good idea to flush a stream before closing it:

```
    write.print(everyThing);
    write.flush(); //since the printwriter you're using does not autoflush
    write.close();
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, you may want to try closing the scanner once your done reading and THEN creating the PrintWriter for writing to the file. I don't see the scanner being closed at all in your example.

Comment: hmmm. sorry to hear that. Try writing form one file and reading from another. That may help you isolate your bug. Writing and reading from the same file in the same method is not something you see very often. Alternatively, simply splitting those processes into two separate method calls may also help you isolate the issue. `readData` and `writeData` get those two methods working on their own, in isolation, and I think you'll have an easier time debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If the first line in your question is accurate ("I am trying to save preferences chosen by user to a text file.") then I wonder if you are not simply doing too much work.

Is there a specific reason you are not using the built-in preferences manager, ala http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html?

Comment: i didn't know about this class. ill have a look at it

Comment: but it seems i will have to rewrite alot of code and i don't want to do that.

Comment: I sympathize with a) wanting to understand why your original code isnt working and b) not wanting to rewrite. But, as for the latter, if you decide to go that way, you may find you are mostly taking your own code out. The pref manager code requires remarkably little code of your own. Less code to do the same thing is almost always better in the long run. Good luck.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a fix. Did one of the answers above help? If so, please mark it as your chosen answer. If not, it would be great if you could add an answer with at least a quick outline of what you did to fix the problem.